Is it possible to transform a video file duration proportionally like things in the 3d workspace?
Ive got a video that is 270 frames. I want the video to gradually shift into slower and slower motion from the 240th frame until its basically at a dead stop on the 270th frame. I figured this would be as simple as turning on proportional editing, setting it to sharp or something, grabbing the 270th frame, expanding the sphere of influence to the last 30 frames, then dragging the 270th frame out to like frame 300 or something. Well there does not appear to be a proportional editing button in the video editor, nor does it appear to be possible to select the last frame of a video file. does anyone know if something like what im looking for is even possible in blender?

so the effect i was trying to achieve is actually very easy! (sorry if this question was too obvious I can take it down) here is a good example of how to slow down or speed up a video properly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaA3VVSmwfo
the video shows visually to soft cut the section of video you want to be effected (using the "k" key), then selecting the video section and "add"ing a "speed control" "effect strip". then depending on how you alter the speed of the cut section you will need to resize the effected section from the "time" portion of the "strip" options. If you double the speed of the effected section then you halve the "duration".
and then if you want to make the shift more gradual instead of sudden animate the speed control multiply factor of the speed effect using keyframes, and to make the video behave smoothly instead of, like, jittery select the interpolation checkbox


Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules links to answers are not answers if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.

thanks Harry! good to know
